# Unbind a tooltip from a svg>rect element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

In the contributions calendar heatmap at https://github.com/ben174?tab=contributions&from=2015-01-27 - I can't seem to figure out how to unbind the tooltip mouseover.

It's like it's showing up without any event bindings, but I can't figure out how that's possible.

Some things I've tried:

```
$("svg rect").unbind("mouseover")
$("svg").unbind("mouseover")
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the source code for this. Since it's hosted on github and their js is minified. Any example I create I could simply unbind. But however they did it on the github website, it doesn't seem to be bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking around at the DOM for several hours. It's not easy to unbind an anonymous function, which is what they had done. You need to *find* the event listener, then *remove* it. This is what ended up working, thanks for the help everyone:

```
getEventListeners(document.querySelectorAll("div.js-calendar-graph")[0]).mouseover[0].remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the parent `<div>` to the `<svg>`,

```
<div class="js-calendar-graph ...etc...">
```

there are mouseover and mouseout events attached to that.  Disabling that mouseover stopped the tooltips appearing for me.

Comment: I did notice that, but I was still unable to programmatically unbind via:  `$(".js-calendar-graph").unbind("mouseover")`

Comment: I'm assuming `unbind()` probably relies on jQuery state. Ie. it only works with events attached with `bind()`. You'll probably have to use the standard DOM `removeEventListener()` function.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure it out: `getEventListeners(document.querySelectorAll("div.js-calendar-graph")[0]).mouseover[0].remove()`